# Oracle Trigger not read

Tags: oracle, triggers, procedure

I have issue with the following trigger.

This is my procedure that counts visits to a page:

```
create or replace procedure VisitSport(idN in number)
is
v1 number := idN;
vc number;
begin
  select s.VISITAS into vc from Sports s where s.IDSPORTS=v1;
  update Sports set VISITAS = vc +1 where IDSPORTS=v1;
end;
```

This is taking the score

```
create or replace PROCEDURE RankingSports(vnumber in number, vid in number)
is
v1 number := vnumber;
v2 number := vid;
v3 number;
begin
select CNT into v3 from SPORTS where IDSPORTS = v2;
update SPORTS set CNT= v3+v1 where IDSPORTS = v2;
end;
```

This is my trigger that makes the operation to calculate a Ranking

```
create or replace trigger trg_RankingSp
after insert or update on Sports
for each row
begin
    update SPORTS set RANKING = visitas/cuenta;
end;
```

This is the error I get when trigger is executed.

> A trigger (or a user defined plsql function that is referenced in
>              this statement) attempted to look at (or modify) a table that was
>              in the middle of being modified by the statement which fired it.
>   *Action:   Rewrite the trigger (or function) so it does not read that table.

Comment: the CNT column in the SPORTS  table is actually called CUENTA

Comment: can you give sample data for `Sports` table and what do you expect after an insert or update, showing some example.

Comment: The base answer is "You can't run a trigger to update the table the trigger is based on."  This is called a mutating table error.  The person that posted the answer is correct syntactically by using ":new.ranking := :new.visitas/:new.cuenta" and he is also correct that you have to do an if statement prior to the assignment because if cuenta is zero, you'll have a divide by 0/null problem.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you want to calculate the `ranking` value only for the row(s) being inserted or updated.  Assuming that is correct, you would just update the `:new` pseudorecord rather than running an `update`.

```
create or replace trigger trg_RankingSp
  after insert or update on Sports
  for each row
begin
    :new.RANKING := :new.visitas/:new.cuenta;
end;
```

Now, if it is possible for `cuenta` to have a value of 0, you'd want to handle that to prevent a division by 0 error.

From a data model standpoint, it seldom makes sense to store a computed value like this.  It would generally make more sense to do the calculation in a view or, potentially, to create a virtual column that is automatically computed.